# href="tel:" -- баг на Андройд

Tags: android, href

Заказчик просить сделать телефоны в разделе контакты, как ссылки; особенно важно для iPhone;

но сейчас я словил баг на Андройд:
дефисы в номере он воспринял как символы и подрезал окончание!!!

```
<a href="tel:7-812-643-21-71">7-812-643-21-71</a>
```

p.s.
номера изначально давались "красивые" и выводятся по принципу `<a href="tel: $param">$param</a>` задача - сохранить максимально читабельность!

Comment: Не проще в атрибуте вырезать всё, кроме цифр?

Comment: А зачем вы используете разделители в `href`?

Comment: на сайте данные фигурируют и в контактах и на гео-карте, мы думали: что достаточно прописать через тире... не факт, что они захотят слитно! http://SSMaker.ru/45e6f1e7/

Answer (score 8):

Пишите вот так

```
<a href="tel:+78126432171">+7 (812) 643-21-71</a>
```

В `href` только цифры, а в теле ссылки в любом формате

Comment: на сайте данные фигурируют и в контактах и на гео-карте, мы думали: что достаточно прописать через тире... не факт, что они захотят слитно! http://SSMaker.ru/45e6f1e7/

Comment: @user1781165 так а в чём проблема писать в `href` слитно, а в теле ссылки и на карте с дефисами?

Comment: @user1781165 собственно, в верху, в шапке на сайте, что вы скинули пример так и сделано

Comment: в href только в международным формате с плюсом. Во внутрь <a></a> пихайте, что хотите и как хотите, хоть в <span> оборачивайте, что бы цифры скакали

Answer (score 0):

Есть целый стандарт https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2806. Но лучше всего зарекомендовала конструкция

```
<a href="tel:+78126432171">код(812) 643-21-71 и что вздумается</a>
```

Телефон в href должен быть в международном формате с плюсом. В `<a></a>` что угодно и как угодно. Оформляйте хоть в `<span>` и `<div>` для задание стилей.

Answer (score -9):

Опытным путём вычислил, что Андройд может принять два дефиса
и забить номер  `<a href="tel:7812-64321-71">7812-64321-71</a>`

Comment: А смысл? Зачем это, что мешает написать в `href` без дефисов? Объясните, нам всем интересно)

Comment: номера изначально давались "красивые"
и выводятся по принципу <a href="tel: $param">$param</a>
задача - сохранить максимально читабельность!

Comment: люди откуда минусы?! я один ответил на свой вопрос!

Comment: Минусы оттуда, что вы не ответили на вопрос, а занимались бессмысленной ерундой. Всё можно было сделать проще и правильней, в чём проблема вырезать регуляркой всё, кроме цифр и подставлять это в `href`, а в тело ссылки подставлять изначальный `$param`?

Comment: @user1781165 Вадим верно подметил. Это - не ответ на вопрос, а велосипед. А заминусовали мы его потому, что в качестве решения нельзя рекомендовать велосипеды другим людям, которые через поиск попадут на ваш вопрос. Есть формат указания номеров внутри href, которого придерживается большинство разработчиков, и который обеспечивает максимальную совместимость со всеми устройствами. Какая разница, красиво он выглядит в атрибуте или нет? Этого никто все равно не увидит. А телефон сам номер отформатирует при нажатии по нему. А внутри <a> вы ведь его можете как угодно записать, хоть римскими цифрами.

Comment: нет не можем - смотрите задание!

Comment: и то, что предложил Вадим не решение (просто я не уточнил этот ньюанс сразу!)